# Adding SSIS to a ADO build server for Build and Deploy

Tags: azure-devops

I have a VSTF build server which we use to build and deploy our applications mostly C#.  I have now been challenged with deploying SSIS packages.  From a manual perspective on my laptop we can get things accomplished, but on the build server we are having issues.  This has been our guide, but it was written in 2017.  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/deployment-automation-for-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/
We are on VSTF2019, VS2019.  On the build server we use only the MSBuild tools, but it seems like SSIS on the build server wants the full UI for VS2019 and SQL Server Management Studio and SSIS.
Our issue is our C-Drive has insufficient space to support these UI's and they don't fully allow us to deploy them to the D-Drive where we have more then enough space.

I am looking for a document or how-to add SSIS (2019) to our build server so that it can be built and deployed using the least amount of space on the c-drive, like build tools. or does SSIS need a build server of its own?

Comment: How is it going with this case? Does below answer help your with above  issue?

Comment: We have install Visual Studio Build tools 2019 on the build server and we are now looking to get a secondary server just for building SSIS packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSDT standalone installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer) to install Integration Services without a SQL server. See [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#install-analysis-services-integration-services-and-reporting-services-tools) for more information.

> does SSIS need a build server of its own?

Building SSIS package needs the required tools(VS2019+SSIS) to be installed in the build server. If this is achievable. You can just install the tools in your existing build server.

Or you can just create on-premise build agent on a new build server which has the tools installed.

If you are able to have a build server with Visual Studio and SSIS designer installed. Deploying SSIS packages would be much easier. You can use the SSIS Build/Deploy task directly in your pipeline. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: But to install a full version of Visual Studio  takes a lot of disk space.  No person is going to use that UI as it is running on a server,  there should be a way to build and deploy SSIS without these UI's being installed.  VS2019 Build tools is not enough?